# Why the Print Op in Tensorflow does not work for me?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried the code below

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(1.0)
a = tf.Print(a, [a], 'hi')
sess = tf.Session()
a.eval(session=sess)
```

but it outputed nothing when I run this python script in shell with the issue `python Print_tf.py`, What's wrong with it? Thanks!

At First, I tried the above code in jupyter notebook and it outputed nothing, then I found sth that said the Print Ops output to the standard error and jupyter notebook cant catch it. But why when I tried in a terminal, it also printed nothing?

By the way, I am using the pip way installed tensorflow_gpu

```
tensorflow-gpu            1.3.0                     <pip>
tensorflow-tensorboard    0.1.8                     <pip>
```

and my shell is zsh on gnome ubuntu 16.04
and I am using anaconda environment.

Comment: I ran your code and it printed the "hi" message. I think your issues are explained in the documentation for `tf.Print`: "This op prints to the standard error. It is not currently compatible with jupyter notebook"

Comment: @MatthewScarpino I have tried to run it in my terminal, but it still output nothing. What can I do?

Comment: I don't know. Your code works on my system. Do you get any output at all? Can you print the value of `a` with the regular Python print function?

Comment: @MatthewScarpino In the above code, I got nothing output, and the system return value is success.  if I add explicitly print statement on a  such as `print(a.eval(session=sess))`, I can get output of `1.0`. It seems correct.

Comment: Some developers suppress TensorFlow messages by setting the `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` environment variable to 2. Are you setting this variable?

Comment: @MatthewScarpino YES! YOU ARE RIGHT! THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: @MatthewScarpino But the `2017-11-22 14:32:14.240535: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
` is really annoying, how can I to suppress it while keep outputing Print information ?

Comment: Sorry. If you don't suppress those messages, the only way to get rid of them is to build TensorFlow from source code.